# How to insert several different columns from source table to one column in destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables in my SQL Server database, Table_1 and Table_2.

- Table_1 has columns: `FirstName`, `fName`, `First_Name`
- Table_2 has one column: `FirstName`.

I need to transfer these three columns from `Table_1` to column `FirstName` in `Table_2`. Each row in `Table_1` has date in only one of these columns and the other two are nulls. I need to copy only that column that contain data.

Does anyone know how to write stored procedure or query that can do this?

[The screenshot is an example of Table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn2Ef.png)

[Second screenshot shows the output I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ2yY.png)

Comment: Check out the `COALESCE` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COALESCE(arg1, arg2, arg3, …), which returns the first non-null value among the arguments. Here's an example matching your sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(25), fName VARCHAR(25), First_Name VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('Sanja', null, null), ('Sanja', null, null), 
    ('Sanja', null, null), (null, null, 'Nick'), (null, 'Bob', null)

INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT COALESCE(FirstName, fName, First_Name) FROM @Table1

SELECT * FROM @Table2

FirstName
Sanja
Sanja
Sanja
Nick
Bob
```